doxygen: I use Markdown pages in the treeview. But there are additional generated md__markdown_files on the Mainpage level
If I use own Markdown pages I see my markdown pages in the tree view. (1)

But there are additional generated pages (2) which are set on the same level as the MainPage.
The Name of the files are the Markdown filename preceded by a md__mark_down_files_2.  E.g. md__mark_down_files_2mainpage.html
Does anyone know how I can get rid of these md__mark_down_files_2* files
Until now I tried to get rid of with using the EXCLUDE, INPUT, FILTER_PATTERN in the Doxyfile. But nothing helped.
I use the version 1.10.0
Content of the Markdown files

Position of the Markdown files in the file system

Html path of expected and unexpected files

Content of the Doxyfile:
    PROJECT_NAME           = MarkDown
    OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = D:\Schrott\DoxygenWithMarkdown
    MARKDOWN_ID_STYLE      = DOXYGEN
    RECURSIVE              = NO
    EXCLUDE                =
    GENERATE_HTML          = YES
    HTML_OUTPUT            = html
    INPUT                  = ./MarkDownFiles \

Mainpage.md
    /*! \mainpage MainPage

    Some general info.

    This manual is divided in the following sections:
    - \subpage SubpageFirstL1
    - \subpage SubpageSecondL1 "Subpage Second L1"

SubpageFirstL1.md
    /*! \page SubpageFirstL1 First L1 

    - \subpage SubpageL2

    This page introduces the user to the topic.
    Now you can proceed to the \ref SubpageSecondL1"Level 1 Second".
    
    
    
    # Here you have a bla
    
    ## and here also
    
    ### und here more bla

SubpageSecondL1.md
    /*! \page SubpageSecondL1 Second L1 
     
    #### this is the Second L1 subpage site

SubpageL2.md
    /*! \page SubpageL2 Sub Page L2

    This page introduces the user to the topic.
    Now you can proceed to the \ref advanced "advanced section".


With the given information it is hard to provide a suggestion / answer, an example with the source code resulting in the image as displayed would help. Please edit this information into the question.

You edited the code as images into the question, never do this as it cannot be cut /pasted by others to replicate the problem, so please add the code to the question (like you already did with the Doxyfile)

Looks like you are (even incompletely) mixing 2 comment styles. 1) markdown md file-style which requires no /*! and the, original / older, doc / h- file style where the comments / texts  like these should be used inside C / Cpp comment blocks. BY removing the /*! you will, as far as I can see, be able to obtain the required results.

Hello Albert,
thank you for your help. It worked.
remove the "/*!" removed the additional sites, but the tree view is still there.
